# SQL: Computing sum of all values *and* a sum of only values matching condition

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sum, aggregate-functions

Suppose I fetch a set of rows from several tables. I want to know the total sum of values in column `x` in these rows, as well as sum of only those values in `x` where the row satisfies some additional condition.

For example, let's say I fetched:

```
 X   Y
 1   0
10   0
20 100
35 100
```

I want to have a sum of all `x` (66) and `x` in those rows where `x` > `y` (11). So, I'd need something like:

```
SELECT sum(x) all_x, sum(x /* but only where x > y */) some_x FROM ...
```

Is there a way to formulate that in SQL? (Note that the condition is not a separate column in some table, I cannot group over it, or at least don't know how to do that.)

**EDIT**: I use Oracle Database, so depending on Oracle extensions is OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression inside the `sum`:

```
SELECT SUM (x) all_x, 
       SUM (CASE WHEN x > y THEN x ELSE 0 END) some_x 
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Thanks, I guessed it was something simple. Will accept once Stackoverflow allows me.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `CASE` operator :

```
SELECT sum(X) all_x, 
       sum(CASE WHEN X>Y THEN X ELSE 0 END) some_x 
FROM Table1
```

In this case (no pun) you would get 11 for `some_x`
You can use whatever condition you want instead of `X>Y` after the `WHEN`, and select whatever value instead of `X`.

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b2ae/1) to test this query.

Answer (score 2):

Below Query will give What you want

```
select SUM(x) as x,(select SUM(x) from test5 where x>y )as 'X>Y'
from test5
```

Comment: Not in Oracle. Sql Server yes, other databases maybe, but Oracle will think you're trying to group on the second column without specifying a `GROUP BY` clause, and the query will fall over.